# Fotos proporcionales

Tags: html, css

Veran, en una vista tengo este código:

```
<img class="card-img-top" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;" src="{{url($foto->ruta())}}"/>
```

Este código hace que se muestre en pantalla una imagen, y dicha imagen se le modificara el tamaño a 400 pixeles de ancho y 300 de alto.
Yo quiero que mi imagen tenga 300 pixeles de alto, pero el ancho sea proporcional al ancho original.

Si la foto tenia originalmente 800x600, que al mostrarse tenga 400x300, y si tenia 100x150, se muestre en pantalla como 200x300.
¿Como lo hago?

Comment: Lo mejor que puedes hacer es usar un editor de imagenes y cambiar el tamaño por tu cuenta.

Comment: si no le pones ancho o le das un `width:auto` lo calcula solo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con auto

```html
<img class="card-img-top" style="width: auto; height: 300px;" src="{{url($foto->ruta())}}"/>
```